# Flattening dictionary with pd.json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

I am currently working on flattening this dictionary file and have reached a number of road blocks. I am trying to use `json_normalize` to flatten this data. If I test with individual instances it works but if I want to flatten all the data it will return an error stating `key error '0'` I'm not sure how to fix this.

example of the data-

```
data = {1:{
      'Name': "Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['123445452543'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345']},
     2:{
      'Name': "boring Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['111111', '1121111'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353', '4324232342'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345', '4353543']}}
```

my code

```
d_flat = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, meta=['Title', 'StoreID', 'BookID', 'SalesID'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setup

Your data is structured inconveniently.  I want to focus on:

1. Getting the lists in `'IDs'` into a list of dictionaries, which would be far more convenient.
2. Getting rid of the useless keys in the parent dictionary.  All we care about are the values.

Your `data`:

```
{1: {'Name': 'Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers',
     'IDs': {'StoreID': ['123445452543'],
             'BookID': ['543533254353'],
             'SalesID': ['543267765345']}},
 2: {'Name': 'boring Tales of Dragon Slayers',
     'IDs': {'StoreID': ['111111', '1121111'],
             'BookID': ['543533254353', '4324232342'],
             'SalesID': ['543267765345', '4353543']}}}
```

What I want it to look like:

```
[{'Name': 'Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers',
  'IDs': [{'StoreID': '123445452543',
           'BookID': '543533254353',
           'SalesID': '543267765345'}]},
 {'Name': 'boring Tales of Dragon Slayers',
  'IDs': [{'StoreID': '111111',
           'BookID': '543533254353',
           'SalesID': '543267765345'},
          {'StoreID': '1121111',
           'BookID': '4324232342',
           'SalesID': '4353543'}]}]
```

---

### Restructure Data

#### Reasonable Way

Simple loop, don't mess around.  This gets us what I showed above

```
new = []

for v in data.values():
    temp = {**v}           # This is intended to keep all the other data that might be there
    ids = temp.pop('IDs')  # I have to focus on this to create the records
    temp['IDs'] = [dict(zip(ids, x)) for x in zip(*ids.values())]
    new.append(temp)
```

#### Cute one-liner

```
new = [{**v, 'IDs': [dict(zip(v['IDs'], x)) for x in zip(*v['IDs'].values())]} for v in data.values()]
```

### Create `DataFrame` with `pd.json_normalize`

In this call to `json_normalize` we need to specify the path to the records, i.e. the list of id dictionaries found at the `'IDs'` key.  `json_normalize` will create one row in the dataframe for every item in that list.  This will be done with the the `record_path` parameter and we pass a `tuple` that describes the path (if it were in a deeper structure) or a string (if the key is at the top layer, which for us, it is).

```
record_path = 'IDs'
```

Then we want to tell `json_normalize` what keys are metadata for the records.  If there are more than one record, as we have, then the metadata will be repeated for each record.

```
meta = 'Name'
```

So the final solution looks like this:

```
pd.json_normalize(new, record_path='IDs', meta='Name')

        StoreID        BookID       SalesID                               Name
0  123445452543  543533254353  543267765345  Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers
1        111111  543533254353  543267765345     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers
2       1121111    4324232342       4353543     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers
```

---

### However

If we are restructuring anyway, might as well make it so we can just pass it to the dataframe constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame([
    {'Name': r['Name'], **dict(zip(r['IDs'], x))}
    for r in data.values() for x in zip(*r['IDs'].values())
])

                                Name       StoreID        BookID       SalesID
0  Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers  123445452543  543533254353  543267765345
1     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers        111111  543533254353  543267765345
2     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers       1121111    4324232342       4353543
```

---

### Bonus Content

While we are at it.  The data is ambiguous in regards to whether or not each id type has the same number of ids.  Suppose they did not.

```
data = {1:{
      'Name': "Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['123445452543'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345']}},
     2:{
      'Name': "boring Tales of Dragon Slayers",
      'IDs':{
            "StoreID": ['111111', '1121111'],
            "BookID": ['543533254353', '4324232342'],
            "SalesID": ['543267765345', '4353543', 'extra id']}}}
```

Then we can use `zip_longest` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

pd.DataFrame([
    {'Name': r['Name'], **dict(zip(r['IDs'], x))}
    for r in data.values() for x in zip_longest(*r['IDs'].values())
])

                                Name       StoreID        BookID       SalesID
0  Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers  123445452543  543533254353  543267765345
1     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers        111111  543533254353  543267765345
2     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers       1121111    4324232342       4353543
3     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers          None          None      extra id
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to read `data`
2. Convert the values in the `'IDs'` column to separate columns

   - `.pop` removes the old column from `df`
   - `pd.DataFrame(df.pop('IDs').values.tolist())` converts each `dict key` to a separate column
   - `.join` the new columns back to `df`
3. [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) each `list` in the columns, with `.apply`.

- Depending on the data, sometimes the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465134/7758804) is to reshape the data, as shown by [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared)

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data =\
{1: {'IDs': {'BookID': ['543533254353'],
             'SalesID': ['543267765345'],
             'StoreID': ['123445452543']},
     'Name': 'Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers'},
 2: {'IDs': {'BookID': ['543533254353', '4324232342'],
             'SalesID': ['543267765345', '4353543'],
             'StoreID': ['111111', '1121111']},
     'Name': 'boring Tales of Dragon Slayers'}}

# load the data using from_dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)

# convert IDs to separate columns
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('IDs').values.tolist()))

# explode the list in each column
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df)
                                Name        BookID       SalesID       StoreID
0  Thrilling Tales of Dragon Slayers  543533254353  543267765345  123445452543
1     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers  543533254353  543267765345        111111
2     boring Tales of Dragon Slayers    4324232342       4353543       1121111
```

Comment: best solution imo